# parallelism: the farther/the more

Tags: grammar, parallelism, correlative-comparatives

I edited this phrase:

*the farther the negative from the lens, the more light needed to expose it properly and the longer the exposure*

to read:

*the farther the negative from the lens, the greater the amount of light needed to expose it properly and the longer the exposure*

I am sure the former is not grammatical but I am having a hard time explaining why the edit is necessary. Can someone help?

Comment: Well, first of all, why delete _is_? That's what causes the trouble. _The farther the negative is from the lens, the more light is needed to expose it properly, and the longer the exposure is._ Start with complete sentences.

Comment: The thing that troubles me about adding "is" is that then it sounds like "light is needed more" to expose the negative: "the farther the negative is from the lens, the more light is needed to expose it properly..."

Comment: Well, if more light is needed, then light is needed more, right? That's not the idiom, but you can read it that way if you like, and it means the same thing.

Comment: I don't think it is exactly the same thing, tho. One always needs light to make a photographic print, but when printing from a negative made using a longer camera lens, one needs MORE light (a greater amount). I am mostly interested in understanding the grammatical difference between "the more" and "the greater the amount" in this context. I know there is one, but I can't quite diagram it for myself.

Comment: @Bismarck_Felix, I don't see any semantic difference between "*more light*" and "*greater amount of light*". Do you feel there's a difference between "*more water*" and "*a greater amount of water*", or is *light* somehow special?

Comment: If you want to make a disquisition on optics and geometry, don't try to do it in three reduced clauses. Go ahead. Spend a period. Make several sentences; they don't cost that much.

Comment: @DanBron: the distinction is between _light is needed more_ and _more light is needed_, and indeed, the sentence can be read both ways. However, as an avid amateur photographer, I immediately read the sentence in the intended way. "Light is needed more" makes little sense in this context. I don't think many readers would be confused.

Comment: @JohnLawler: maybe he is trying to communicate the basics of photography over the good old telegraph. Sentences can be quite expensive in that case. I would advise against that practice though. Explain stop STOP.

Comment: @DanBron. Hmm. "The bigger the fire, the more water needed to quench it." That does seem better to me. Perhaps the problem is just that a  misreading intrudes upon my mind, with "water" as subject of the verb "to need": the bigger the fire, the more water needed [desired, was compelled] to quench it"—and so an alarm is going off in my head...erroneously.

Comment: Interestingly, the meaning that you wish to avoid becomes the obvious one in the water example if _is_ is included: “The bigger the fire, the more water is needed to quench it”. Here I immediately read it as “the more you need water to quench it” rather than “the more water you need to quench it”. This differs from the photography example where I immediately read it as “the more light you need to expose it properly”. (Incidentally, using _you_ is unambiguous and more elegant than _the greater amount of_, if you ask me: “The farther the negative is from the lens, the more light you need…”.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes! Much better edit of the original; it completely eliminates the ambiguity that was bothering me and is less of an intervention in the text.